# this.State is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am having trouble figuring out why this.state is undefined.

When the start button is first clicked `updateBoard()` and `startGame()` are called. The **first** time `startGame()` is called it runs okay, and at the end of it the states are changed then the board is re-rendered.

After the re-render `componentDidUpdate()` is called and `setTimeout()` is started that calls `this.startGame` after 1000ms. Once that **second** `startGame()` is run, I get...

`TypeError: this.state is undefined` for the first `if()` in the `startGame()` function.

### This is the code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/JeremyWeisener/pen/VrYGvV)

### This is the code from codepen right here

```
const Board = (props) => {
  
  var size = props.boardSize;
  var row = 0;
  
  const toggleCell = (el) => {
    
    var ele = document.getElementById(el);
    
    if(ele.className == 'off'){
      ele.className = 'on';
    }
    else{
      ele.className = 'off';
    }
    
  }
  
  const cols = (rows) => {
      
      if(props.state.board[0][0] != undefined){

          return props.state.board[row].map((data2, index2) => {
              
            var id = '' + row + '-' + index2;
            return (<td onClick={toggleCell.bind(this, id)} id={`${rows}-${index2}`} className={`${data2}`}> </td>);
          });
      }
      else{
          
          return props.state.board.map((data2, index2) => {
             
            var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            var choice = '';
             
            if(rand<22){
             choice = 'on';
            }
            else{
                choice = 'off';
            }
              
            var id = '' + row + '-' + index2;
            
            return (<td onClick={toggleCell.bind(this, id)} id={`${rows}-${index2}`} className={`${choice}`}> </td>);
          });
      }
      
    
  }
  
  const genCells = props.state.board.map((data, index) => {
      row = index;
            return (<tr id={`row${index}`} row={index}> {cols(index)} </tr>);
      });
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1 id="title"> The Game of Life </h1>
        <h5 id="generations">Gen: {props.state.gens}</h5>
        <table id="life">
          {genCells}
        </table>
      </div>
      
      <div id="buttons">
        <button onClick={() => {props.createBoard(20)}}  className="btn btn-primary sizes"> 20 x 20 </button>
        <button onClick={() => {props.createBoard(30)}}  className="btn btn-primary sizes"> 30 x 30 </button>
        <button onClick={() => {props.createBoard(40)}} className="btn btn-primary sizes"> 40 x 40 </button>
      </div>
      <div id="options">
        <button onClick={() => {props.toggleRun(true); props.startGame();}}     className="btn btn-success sizes"> Start </button>
        <button onClick={() => {props.toggleRun(false)}}                    className="btn btn-warning sizes"> Pause </button>
        <button onClick={() => {props.clearBoard()}}                        className="btn btn-danger sizes">  Reset </button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    );
}
```

.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            newGame: true,
            gens: 0,
            nextGen: [],
            size: 0,
            board: [],
            running: false
        }
      }
  
    createBoard(dim) {

        //If a number is given (60, 80, 120), generate the board
        if(dim>0){
            //create empty 'board'-Array
            var board = [];
            //create rows and col in 'board'-Array
            for(var i=0;i<dim;i++){
              let temp = new Array(dim);
              board.push(temp);
            }
            //set new array to 'board'-State(Array)
            this.setState({
              board: board, 
              size: dim
            });
        }
        else{
            
        }
        
        
    }
  
    updateBoardState(newBoard){
      var board = this.state.board;
      var length = board.length;
      
      if(newBoard == undefined){
          var newBoard = board;
          
          for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
              for(var j=0;j<length;j++){
                  
                  newBoard[i][j] = document.getElementById(''+i+'-'+j).className;
                  
              }
            }
          
          
      }
      
      if(newBoard != undefined){
      
            for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
              for(var j=0;j<length;j++){
                  
                  document.getElementById(''+i+'-'+j).className = newBoard[i][j];
                  
              }
            }
        
      
        
            this.setState({board:newBoard, 
                    gens: this.state.gens++});
        }
    
      //console.log("board Updated!");
    }
  
    toggleRun(boo){
        this.updateBoardState();
        this.setState({running: boo});
    }
  
    clearBoard(){
        var ons = document.getElementsByClassName('on');
        //console.log(ons);
        for(var i=0;i<ons.length;i++){
          ons[i].className='off';
          i--;
        }
    } 
  
    startGame(){
        
        
        if(this.state.running == true){
            var board = this.state.board;
            var size = this.state.size;
            var newBoard = board;
            
            for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
                for(var j=0;j<size;j++){
                    
                    //Declarations
                    let aliveNeighbours = 0;
                    
                    var target = document.getElementById(''+i+'-'+j);
                    
                    //Neigbours
                    
                    var neighblocks = new Array();
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    neighblocks.push(document.getElementById(''+(i-1)+'-'+(j-1)));
                    neighblocks.push(document.getElementById(''+(i-0)+'-'+(j-1)));
                    neighblocks.push(document.getElementById(''+(i+1)+'-'+(j-1)));
                    
                    neighblocks.push(document.getElementById(''+(i-1)+'-'+(j-0)));
                    neighblocks.push(document.getElementById(''+(i+1)+'-'+(j-0)));
                    
                    neighblocks.push(document.getElementById(''+(i-1)+'-'+(j+1)));
                    neighblocks.push(document.getElementById(''+(i-0)+'-'+(j+1)));
                    neighblocks.push(document.getElementById(''+(i+1)+'-'+(j+1)));
                    
                    
                    //Check if Neighbour is alive 
                    //(results in `aliveNeighbours`)
                    neighblocks.forEach(function(el){
                        if(el != null){
                            if(el.className == 'on'){
                                aliveNeighbours++;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    });
                    
                    //console.log("cell#"+i+"-"+j+" alive neighbours = " + aliveNeighbours);
                    
                    
                    
                    //RULES
                    if(aliveNeighbours<2){
                        //die of isolation
                        newBoard[i][j] = 'off';
                        //console.log("neighbour killed!");
                        
                    }
                    if(aliveNeighbours == 2){
                        //live on
                        if(target.className == 'on'){
                            newBoard[i][j] = 'on';
                            //console.log("surviver");
                        }
                    }
                    if(aliveNeighbours > 3){
                        //die of over population
                        newBoard[i][j] = 'off';
                        //console.log("death!");
                        
                    }
                    if(aliveNeighbours == 3){
                        //live on / give birth
                        newBoard[i][j] = 'on';
                        //console.log("its a boy!");
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
      
       for(let a=0;a<size;a++){
          for(let b=0;b<size;b++){
            var eel = document.getElementById(''+a+'-'+b);
            eel.className = newBoard[a][b];
          }
      }
      
      
      //this.updateBoardState(newBoard);
            
        }        
    
    }
  
    componentWillMount(){
        if(this.state.newGame){
            this.createBoard(8);
            this.setState({newGame: false, 
                    running: true});
        }
    }
  
    componentDidUpdate(){
    var startGamee = this.startGame;
    console.log(this.startGame);
    
            setTimeout(this.startGame, 1000);
    }
  
  render(){
      
    return (
      <div>
        
        <div>
          <Board    createBoard={this.createBoard.bind(this)} 
                            toggleRun={this.toggleRun.bind(this)} 
                            clearBoard={this.clearBoard.bind(this)} 
                            state={this.state}
                            updateBoardState={this.updateBoardState.bind(this)} 
                            startGame={this.startGame.bind(this)}
                    />
        </div>
        
      </div>
    )
    
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more minimal example of your problem:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "test"
  }
  startGame() {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
  delay() {
    setTimeout(this.startGame, 1000)
  }
}

let t = new Test
t.startGame() // <- this works
t.delay()    // <- probably not what you're hoping for
```

You will see that `delay()` logs `undefined` or something from the window object. This is because `this` is determined by the calling location of the function. In the case of `setTimeout`, `this` no longer points to your class because it's not being called like `t.startGame()`. `setTimeout` is calling it and `this` is pointing to whatever `setTimeout` thinks `this` is.

One easy way to fix it, is to use an arrow function in the timeout:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "test"
  }
  startGame() {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
  delay() {
    setTimeout(() => this.startGame(), 1000)
  }
}

let t = new Test
t.startGame()
t.delay()
```

Another way is to pass a function explicitly bound to your class with:

```
delay(){
    setTimeout(this.startGame.bind(this), 1000)
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation - whoever downvoted it wasn't reading carefully.

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution I used so I'm marking it as the right answer. I think my error was that I was trying to write an anonymous function in ES5 using `function(){this.startGame()}` but it wasn't working. You rock!

Answer (score 2):

In your `componentDidMount()` method, you need to bind `this.startGame()` in order to have access to state. See below:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    var startGame = this.startGame;
    console.log(this.startGame);

    setTimeout(this.startGame.bind(this), 1000); // bound to `this`
}
```

This is because `setTimeout()` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind `startGame()` to the `App` component in the constructor, so the function has the correct lexical scope. In the `App` constructor:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            newGame: true,
            gens: 0,
            nextGen: [],
            size: 0,
            board: [],
            running: false
        }
        this.startGame = this.startGame.bind(this)
      }
```

Comment: He already bound `startGame()` where it was called in the `render()` method.

Comment: No - he bound it for the startGame prop but not for the setTimeout.